# Confusion on Shannon's joint entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Given the definition of Shannon's joint entropy $H(X,Y) = -\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)log(p(x,y))$, I am not sure of how to compute it for a distribution of random variables such as $X = p$ and $Y = 1 - p$. It seems to be very simple but I think I misunderstood the defition.
This ptoblem came from an exercise from Nielsen and Chuang's book:

"*Suppose*
$
\rho = p\lvert0\rangle\langle0\rvert + \dfrac{(1-p)}{2}(\lvert0\rangle+\lvert1\rangle)(\langle0\lvert + \langle1\lvert)
$

*Evaluate* $S(\rho)$ and $H(p,1-p)$"

I am stucked in evaluating the Shannon's entropy.

The factor $p(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution, so it can be written as $p(x,y) = p(Y = y|X=x)p(X=x)$

But, for $X = p$ and $Y = 1-p$ how can I compute $H(X = p , Y =1-p)$? how can the result of this be different from the binary entropy when $X$ is distributed as $p$ and $1-p$?

Is $H(X = p , Y = 1 - p) = -\sum_{x,y}p(p , 1-p)log(p(p,1-p))$ = $p(Y = 1-p|X = p)p(X = p)log(p(Y = 1-p|X = p)p(X = p)) = (1-p)p\times log((1-p)p)$?

If not, what concept am I missing?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, you can't just say "$X=p$". The random variable $X$ is defined by a _distribution_ of outcomes. So, for example, you could say that $X$ is a discrete random variable distributed such that it has a probability $p$ of having the value $0$ and a probability $1-p$ of having the value $1$.

Comment: @probably_someone I see what you mean, and that is the origin of my misundertanding: the exercise (from Nielsen and Chuang's book) says "compute H(p,1-p)". Am I supposed to interpret this as if X "is distributed such that it has a probability p of having the value 0 and a probability 1-p of having the value 1"? And what about Y? Is it distributed in such a way that as X has value 1 it has value 0 and vice versa?

Comment: I eddited, maybe the question is clearer now. Thanks for the comments

Comment: @Dimitri Unless it's specifically referring to a joint entropy in the question, I would assume that $H(p,1-p)$ refers to the Shannon entropy of a single random variable with two possible outcomes, not the joint Shannon entropy. The notation is definitely not optimal here.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, I would assume that too; in this case I can work out the exercise with no problem. Maybe is the notation that got me, because it is indeed not optimal. I interpreted it as the notation for the joint entropy as he used in the book. Anyway, without knowing anything about the distributions I cannot do anything. Thank you.

Comment: @Dimitri You have the distribution. It's given right there. There are two possible outcomes for the random variable (call them whatever you want, $a$ and $b$ maybe, it doesn't matter for entropy calculations, only the probabilities do). Outcome $a$ has probability $p$ of happening, and outcome $b$ has probability $1-p$ of happening.

Comment: @probably_someone yes; sorry, what I meant with "without knowing anything about the distributions" I was referring to two different distributions for computing joint entropy. Interpreting the exercise as the entropy of a single random variable with two outcomes is no problem, I can work out. :)) I was not clear in my last comment

Comment: I've voted to close, since it has turned out that the question is about a misunderstood notation -- not about the mathematics involved.